# onclick function not working when rendered in ts file (Angular 4 & ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hey guys I want to know how to call a function while rendering html in .ts file.I have tried it my project, i am able to show the image tag but not able to call a function when clicked on the image..is their any other way to fix this?

```
  commonFunctionActive(nullDataActive) {
    console.log("NEWACCOUNTOPENING");

    let str = "";
    if (nullDataActive == "New Customer Active") {
      str = '<img  class="imgActiveCust" src ="assets/member_images/viewCustomer.jpg"  onclick="myFunction()" alt="">';

    } else {
      str = nullDataActive
    }

    return (str);
  }


  myFunction() {
    console.log("customererrrrererer");

    let self = this;
    if (self.nullDataActive.customer_id != "") {
      self.navCtrl.push("CustomerPage");
    }
    else {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Try to use `(click)="myFunction()"` instead `onclick="myFunction()"` that's the right directive for angular code.

Comment: Thanks Simo. i have tried using (click) directive..its not working

Comment: Can you show us how you insert your html string in your template? Maybe is a Html sanitizing issue.
Then when you click the image, some error pop up in console?

Comment: please post your html code here.. so that we can help you! :). because the way you might be using, could be affecting the DOM (according to angular by default you can not use external scripts in angular, so called DOM sanitizing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is simple: you're using onclick, but in angular 2+ you should use (click)="myFunction()"

Read more at MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Comment: i have tried using (click) directive..its not working

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way :  (click)="myFunction()"

Comment: Thanks abhishek... i have tried using (click) its not working

Comment: @Tanmay tell me one thing are you testing on emulator or on mobile device?

Comment: i am testing it on emulator